# Hibernate not resuming properly Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: hibernate

I want to hibernate my laptop, but everytime I do it behaves like I restarted it. I use KDE Plasma and I hibernate using the shutdown options. It jumps to the lockscreen and flashes on and off once or twice before shutting down. When I then power the laptop on, I get a `Resuming from dev/disk/...` right below the PC logo after which it jumps back to the lockscreen bit immediately proceeds to return to the main login screen. I'm sure that the hibernate worked relatively well because when I then login again, it doesn't take any time at all for the desktop to load.

Can anyone help me debug this? My laptop doesn't have a battery, so I've always hibernated my PC in order to move it around. Switching to Ubuntu has forced me to shut it down if I want to change rooms